# Spring Security with Apache CXF jaxrs without using a web.xml

Tags: spring-security, cxf

I'm implementing a REST service with Apache CXF and trying to use spring-security for authentication and authorization. 
Embedded Jetty has been used as the container thus not using a `web.xml`.

How can I initialize spring-security filter chain with Apache CXF without using a `web.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Servlet API 3.1 you can implement [`AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.html), see [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer-with-spring-mvc):

> ```
> import org.springframework.security.web.context.*;
>
> public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
>
> }
> ```
>
> This would simply only register the springSecurityFilterChain Filter for every URL in your application.

Comment: But we need to somehow provide the DelegatingFilterProxy to the jetty container. How can we do that with java based configuration ? Isn't it the same thing as with the XML configuration except we code the configuration in java instead of using XML ?